# How to Deploy a TMS WEB CORE Application?

Tags: tms-web-core

I’m new to TMS Web Core and transitioning from Intraweb. I’m looking for a straightforward tutorial or guide that can walk me through the process of deploying a TMS WEB CORE application.

Currently, I have a TMS WEB server set up on my development machine. I assume I’ll need a server on the destination computer as well. Could someone provide detailed steps on how to install and configure the server for deployment purposes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!